# How to decode data parameter under logs in transaction receipt?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, dapps, events, logs

I went through many questions but I couldn't get my answer.

web3 version -- `0.20.6`

According to documentation event parameters that are not indexed, store in data parameters under logs. I want to iterate over blocks and store data from events.
How can I decode the `data` parameter?

I went through this link https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-ethereum-logs-a8d2047c7371 but was unable to understand how he decoded that data.

```
event Record(string location, uint256 temperature);
 
function recordData(string location, uint256 temperature) public {
    emit Record(location, temperature);
}
```

Input is given: `London, 25`

data:

> "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064c6f6e646f6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

topic:
`0xaa39dce7cd051e04c98757533bc6e3eb213cccafa31717ca09ef4dde19f123f5`
[image: data parameter under logs]

I ran the same parameter transaction in remix and logs don't have any data parameter. In receipt there is input parameter. The input parameter must be the parameter that I passed, am i correct?

input:

> "0xbc820aa40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064c6f6e646f6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to deal with raw data I'd suggest to use a library like [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi). The rules used to encode/decode are in the [solidity abi](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/abi-spec.html).

In your case your data split into chunks of 20 bytes/40 hex look like

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
4c6f6e646f6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The first parameter `location` is a string, since strings are of variable length they store an offset instead of the value. So `0x00..040 = 64` is the offset to the `location` parameter.

The second parameter `temperature` is uint256, and it fits in 32 bytes so its value is stored directly. Value is then `0x00..001d = 29`.

The event doesn't have more parameters and the rest of the data is used by the parameters like `location` that were not included directly.

The parameter `location` is at offset `0x40 = 64` and we have this data

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
4c6f6e646f6e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Strings are array of bytes, the first slot is length in this case `0x00..06 = 6` are the length of our string. The rest are the data of our string, the first six bytes are `4c6f6e646f6e`. Using `web3.toAscii("4c6f6e646f6e") == 'London'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ismael for the explanation. Now I understood better. Can you please tell which method is used in this link's description to decode data? https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-ethereum-logs-a8d2047c7371

Comment: The article has a line `values = eth_abi.decode_abi(types, log['data'])` that decodes the data from the arguments types.

Answer (score 1):

In Remix, you're seeing the event log delimited as described here:

> event Record(string location, uint256 temperature);

You see the values provided by index (0,1) and by name (location, temperature). Length is self-explanatory.

You're in a "deep dive" and you're getting pretty raw data pretty "close to the metal". A higher-level abstraction can get you closer to an application-level view of the information. You can use something like Truffle with its "truffle-contract" wrapper.

In that case, the software client (JavaScript) will have inbuilt awareness of how the data is delimited and will unpack it for you.

It would be something like:

```
var reportLog;
reportLog = myContractInstance.Report({}); // possibility of filters    
reportLog.watch(function(err,res) {
     // you get here when an event is received
     console.log(res.args); // res.args.location, res.args.temperature
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I knew about watch and get function but I was hoping to get the input from "data" parameter. I have tried the below filter but it is giving data from latest block only: reportLog = myContractInstance.Report({fromBlock:1, toBlock:'latest'});